# What's the difference between findOneAndUpdate and findOneAndReplace?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I've recently installed the Java MongoDB Driver 3.1.1 version and I'm wondering what's the difference between `findOneAndUpdate` and `findOneAndReplace`?

In what situation should i use each one?

Comment: [findOneAndReplace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/) vs [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `findOneAndUpdate` searches the document and updates just the entries in the given update document. The other entries in the found document will remain.

The `findOneAndReplace` searches the document, removes **everything** inside this document and sets the entries of the given replacement document.

**For example:**
You have a document `{"name":"James", "age":"21"}`

If you use the `findOneAndUpdate` function with the update document `{"age":"22"}`, you will get the document `{"name":"James", "age":"22"}`

If you use the `findOneAndReplace` function with the replacement document `{"age":"22"}`, you will get the document `{"age":"22"}` (The name has been deleted)

See: [findOneAndUpdate Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) and [findOneAndReplace Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndReplace/)

Comment: Good answer. It might also be worth noting how they match up with their corresponding HTTP methods. `findOneAndReplace()` matches with `PUT` while `findOneAndUpdate()` matches with `PATCH`.

Comment: Will mongo be smart about reindexing when using replace?