# The replacement document must not contain atomic operators

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've this function for save new record or update an existing item:

```
async function saveEmploy(c){
let employ=new collaboratore();
employ=c;
let docs=c.documenti.length>0?c.documenti:undefined;
if(docs!==undefined){
    let oldDocs=docs.map(d=>{if (d._id) d;});
    oldDocs.forEach(async d=>{
        let oldDoc=await documento.findOneAndReplace({_id:doc._id},doc,{upsert:true});
        employ.documenti.push(oldDoc._id);
    });
    let newDocs=docs.map(d=>{if(!d._id)d;});
    newDocs.forEach(async d=>{
        let newDoc=await d.save();
        employ.documenti.push(newDoc._id);
    });
}

let savedEmploy=null;
if(c._id){
    savedEmploy=await collaboratore.findOneAndReplace({_id:c._id},employ,{new:true,upsert:true});
}
else
    savedEmploy=await employ.save();
console.log('saved');
return savedEmploy;
}
```

These are the schemas:

```
const collaboratoreschema =new schema({
   dataregistrazione:{type:Date,default:Date.now},
   nominativo:nominativoschema,
   localitanascita:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
   provincianascita:{type:String,required:true,trim:true},
   datanascita:{type:Date,required:true},
   indirizzoresidenza:{type:indirizzoEmbeddedSchema,required:true},
   indirizzodomicilio:{type:indirizzoEmbeddedSchema,set:v=>!v || v.length===0?undefined:v},
   telefoni:{type:[telefonoschema],required:true},
   indirizziemail:{type:[require('../email.schema.js')],set:v=>!v || v.length===0?undefined:v},
   codicefiscale:{type:String,required:true,uppercase:true,trim:true,match:/^[a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]$/},
   note:{type:String,trim:true,set:v=>!v || v===''?undefined:v},
   immagine:imageEmbeddedSchema,
   documenti:[{type:schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'tbFiles'}],
   datainiziorapporto:{type:Date,required:true},
   datafinerapporto:Date,
   riferimentoazienda:{type:schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'tbFornitori',set:v=>!v || v==={} || v===''?undefined:v},
   attivo:{type:Boolean,default:true}
},{timestamps:true,useNestedStrict: true,collection:'tbCollaboratori'});
```

When I execute the findOneAndReplace function, I get this error:

> The replacement document must not contain atomic operators.

I don't undestand where is my mistake.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your update document, either `doc` or `employ`, contains update operations (`$set: {...}`). 
As the name suggests, [findOneAndReplace](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndReplace) **replaces** contents of the document, so update operators are not allowed here. 
Most probably you need to use [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) here or make sure your update document contains an entire new record. 
Refer to this post [What's the difference between findOneAndUpdate and findOneAndReplace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153460/whats-the-difference-between-findoneandupdate-and-findoneandreplace) and this article [MongoDB findOneAndDelete findOneAndUpdate findOneAndReplace](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/mongodb-findoneanddelete-findoneandupdate-findoneandreplace-690) for details as well.

Comment: "...contains update operations `$set: {...})`" and how do we know?